# Did early versions of jQuery (1.2.3) use a plain 'j' as its namespace alias?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking at some old jQuery coding and see this a few times:

```
    j(document).ready(function(){
         j('body,html').animate({
            ...
```

Was j used as an alias in early versions of jQuery?

Comment: You can choose whatever alias you want using `noConflict()`.  See http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: *"Was j used as an alias in early versions of jQuery?"* No. [Looking at the jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/d9a3c4fefaf84db7eba9b1f8204d1e134266b823/jquery.js#L27) confirms that. You are also free to assign `$` or `jQuery` to any variable you want to, even without using `noConflict`.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd expect to see the alias reassignment soon after <script>, but I don't.  Also ran into this: $(document).ready(function(){
  j('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
   }, 200);
 tooltip();
}); Which may explain why some things are not working here.